# How to scrape url using Scrapy in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract the entire product url from the link "http://presskr.com/category/Mobiles--Tablets/35" using scrapy in python. Below is the function I'm using to do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print("hello");

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="pagination_contents"]')
    items = []
    i=3
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['link'] = site.select('div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/a/@href').extract()
        i=int(i)+1;
        print i
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

The x-path of each product div is: //div[@id="pagination_contents"]/div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/a/@href

But I'm getting only one link and not all the products' url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following. I suggest to follow Scrapy guidelines, just proceed accordingly, you don't need too much manual manipulation. Your example is very much like: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-the-data , so just follow this one further

```
def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//span[@class ="itemlistinginfo"]/a/@href'):
            full_url = urljoin(href.extract())
            item = DmozItem()
            item['link'] = full_url
            yield item
```

Comment: Thank you so much **Turo** i got it